# Android Marshmallow Permissions (MediaPicker/XLabs)

Tags: android, xamarin

I've been working on an app, which incorporates XLabs Nuget packages - to be more specific, I'm using Xlabs in order to utilize cross-platform picture selection in Xamarin.Forms PCL project.

The app compiles without any problems, it works flawlessly on Kitkat, Lolipop and Marshmallow Xamarin Android Emulators.

Now, the problem arises when I export the app and try to run it on physical devices - Android 6.0+. It works without any issues on all Android devices (4.0-5.1) except on Marshmallow, where it hangs every time I try to use MediaPicker to select a Photo from image gallery (when I click on picture from the gallery).

The following asyc code never executes on Marshmallow devices:

```
    private async Task SelectPicture()
    {
        Setup();
        ImageSource = null;
        try
        {
            var mediaFile = await _mediaPicker.SelectPhotoAsync(new CameraMediaStorageOptions
            {
                DefaultCamera = CameraDevice.Front,
                MaxPixelDimension = 400
            });
            ImageSource = ImageSource.FromStream(() => mediaFile.Source);
        }
        catch (System.Exception ex)
        {
            Status = ex.Message;
        }
    }
```

And throws an error if I try tapping picture selection button again:

```
 Only one operation can be active at a time
```

Again, the code Executes perfectly fine on anything below Android 6.0/Marshmallow.

At first I thought I was missing some SKDS and/or latest packages, however that wasn't the case and problem still is present.

Secondly, I have all the necessary permissions Enabled:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

However, now I'm starting to think that these defined permissions alone are not enough. Maybe I need give permission to access and write memory on code behind.

Any tips would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: From android marshmallow on you need to request permissions at runtime. see: https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html

Comment: Also add READ_EXTERNAL_DATA. Because it loads in a picture it might need it.